# Does ongoing damage from the same repeated attack stack?

Tags: dnd-4e

The question is simple but I can't find an answer anywhere:

1. If a creature hits one PC twice with the same attack that inflicts ongoing damage (save ends), does the ongoing damage stack?

   1a) If so, does it require a save for each stack?
2. If two identical creatures hit one PC with the same attack that inflicts ongoing damage (save ends), does the ongoing damage stack?

   2a) If so, does it require a save for each stack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No. You take the maximum ongoing damage of a specific type. If you have 5 fire ongoing and you are hit with another attack that deals 5 fire ongoing then you stay at 5. If you get hit with an attack that deals 10 fire damage then you go to 10 fire damage.

   a. Yes. You must save against each instance of the ongoing damage. Provided they are not identical.
2. No. see answer 1. If the attacks deal the same kind of damage it does not stack. If they deal different kinds of damage then they would stack.

   a. No. *identical* effects are ignored.

Side note, it is always a good idea to try to save, even if you miss the first save as it will be easier to remove the total effect from your character if there are fewer of the same type of thing affecting it.

Comment: I might have to disagree on saves (1a/2a).  By my understanding of the rules, I would say that you have to make saves for each ongoing damage effect until you fail one.  If you save the first one, that does not preclude you from having to make a save again when hit again by the same attack type.  Once you've failed one of the saves, there's no point in continuing to make saves as you're already taking the ongoing damage and it "can't get any worse".

Comment: I stand corrected I looked further and you do have to save against each instance. I will correct the answer. Also its a good idea to save against each one every turn because it will be easier to remove in following turns even if you fail.

Comment: Is this true for untyped ongoing damage too?

Comment: As far as I know yes.

Comment: 2a should be a "no". _If a character is subject to **identical** effects that a save can end, ignore all but one of those effects._ From the _Rules Compendium_ pg 227. Ignore the second `ongoing 5 fire` if you are still subject to the first identical `onging 5 fire` effect.